# Derived Column Find and replace SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a column in a table (say A) which has nulls in it and I have another column (say B) which depends on this column that is they both are interlinked now my problem is
If in A for a row has a `NULL` and B is `NOT NULL` then it A should be replaced by B and if B is also `NULL` along with A then it should assign a value `UNKNOWN`.

```
Table 1:

A    B    C D
NULL 1    2 3
NULL NULL 3 4
1    NULL 4 5
```

Output should be like

```
A       B    C D
1       1    2 3
UNKNOWN NULL 3 4
1       NULL 4 5
```

Comment: Sorry for the mistake updated accoordingly

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The question was on SSIS implementation but I will leave this here for any future souls.

<strike>What about this?</strike>

Edit: Are you wanting to swap A an B? If so, just use a `CASE` similar to this one.

```
CASE [Table 1].A
    WHEN [Table 1].A IS NULL AND [Table 2].B IS NOT NULL
        THEN [Table 1].A
    WHEN [Table 1].A IS NULL AND [Table 2].B IS NULL
        THEN 'UNKNOWN'
    ELSE [Table 1].A
END
```

Comment: I believe they are looking for an SSIS implementation and not a SQL based one

Comment: Thanks for the answer @justin C but as Billinkc said I am looking for an SSIS implementation

Comment: Whoops, my apologies. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

In your derived Column Control add the following experssions depending on your chosen columns (or add new columns )

Column A:

```
((LEN([A]) == 0 || ISNULL([A])) && (LEN([B]) != 0 || !ISNULL([B]))) ? [A] : [B]
```

Column B:

```
((LEN([B]) == 0 || ISNULL([B])) && (LEN([A]) != 0 || !ISNULL([A]))) ? [B] : [A]
```

then you can adapt your UNKNOW case using the same experssion.

```
((LEN([Column 0]) == 0 || ISNULL([Column 0])) && (LEN([Column 1]) == 0 || ISNULL([Column 1]))) ? "HELLO" : "UNKNOW"
```

Keep me updated if it works fine with you :)

Best Regards,
ANDOURA

Comment: can I implement all three in 1 derived column or should create 3 different ones to implement?

Comment: the easier in that case is that you do your work using a script component instead of using expersions in the derived column

Comment: Can you Please help me with script component then? Please :)

Comment: our friend @JustinC has just posted the answer few minutes ago :)
i would add the third case on it:
CASE [Table 1].A
    WHEN [Table 1].A IS NULL AND [Table 2].B IS NOT NULL
        THEN [Table 1].A
    WHEN [Table 1].A IS NOT NULL AND [Table 2].B IS NULL
        THEN [Table 1].B
    ELSE [Table 1].A
END

Answer (score 0):

For column A, use this expression.

```
ISNULL(A) && ISNULL(B)? "UNKNOWN" : ISNULL(A) && !ISNULL(B)? "B" : "NULL"
```